# What layout should I use for a scrollable Jpanel to which I dynamically add elements?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an empty JPanel (imagine it as a fixed-size rectangle) where the user can add identical-size JButtons. They need to be added in a single row, from left to right. When they reach the end of the row, I want them to keep adding in a single row, so I can scroll the JPanel horizontally in order to see all of them.

Essentially, I am asking how to do that. The layout managers posted in Oracle's Visual Guide to Layout Managers either resize the buttons to fit or place them on a new row.

I'm new here so go easy on me :D.

Comment: `GridLayout` or `FlowLayout` should work

Comment: `GridBagLayout` would work, if you're up for the challange